# Programmatic Azure AD Application Discovery

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a service that will be registered in Azure AD as an App. It will have one app registration per region (West US, East US, etc.). Clients calling this service need to acquire an access token. The audience of the access token MUST be the corresponding service for the region. The services are segregated regionally so that an access token for a service in one region cannot be used to access the service in another region. This is by design.

Is there a proper way/recommended best practice for the application discovery?

I have explored the idea of using Graph API. In the model:

1. Each of the registered services will be created using a templatized naming convention e.g. -. There is a concern here that without proper coordination within the tenant where these apps are being registered, we could end up with a name collision.
2. A “discovery app” (application registered for the sole purpose of usage for discovery) will have Application.Read permission the Graph API. Authentication here will be based on a X509 certificate for greater security.
3. Using an access token acquired against the discovery app, Client will query Graph API for the intended service app audience matching on the name. Once that app info is obtained, we’ll have the service app id. Again, concern from #1 above still stands - another application registered with same name will also be found.
4. Client will then use service app id obtained to acquire an access token to talk to the service.

Any help/direction would be much appreciated. Want to make sure I am not re-inventing the wheel if there is already an appropriate pattern to doing this.

Comment: Hi do you have a chance to look into my answer? Is it helpful?

Comment: Thanks @AllenWu, yes I did look at it.  I haven't tried putting the apps into a group yet but  your response helps.  I know the solution I proposed works; My concern here is if there is a recommended (a more proper way) to do this instead of what I had proposed.  As a result, I was waiting a few more days to see if anyone else chimed in.

Comment: Sure:) But in my experience, your design is OK for that and there is no out-of-box solution from MS currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design is feasible. Of course, you need to make reasonable adjustments to the names of app registrations to eliminate the influence of name collision.

I have a suggestion that you could add these service app registrations into a security group and use Microsoft Graph (Beta version) to list them with a filter (templatized naming convention).

Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-5-use-filter-to-get-group-membership-with-a-display-name-that-starts-with-the-letter-a-including-a-count-of-returned-objects):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{id}/members?$count=true&$filter=startswith(displayName, 'a')
ConsistencyLevel: eventual
```

Please note that `$count=true` and request header `ConsistencyLevel: eventual` is necessary.

There is a property `appId` in the response which is what you need. In this way, the influence of name collision can be avoided as much as possible.